# LightDM mysteriously changing monitor layout

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg.conf

**Update:**  The issue seems to stem from LightDM.  If I start my session from a TTY using `startx`, screens are laid out according to `xorg.conf`.  But if I do `sudo start lightdm`, screens become linear even before logging in.

---

I have a single GPU (Nvidia NVS 510) with four monitors attached to it.  I'm trying to arrange them in a 2x2 layout.  However, every time I start X, LightDM seems to reset to a horizontal 1x4 layout.

This is an Ubuntu 14.04 system with proprietary Nvidia drivers installed.  I have generated the following `xorg.conf` using `nvidia-settings`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    [...]
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    [...]
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    [...]
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 510"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-4: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DP-5: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DP-6: nvidia-auto-select +1920+1200, DP-7: nvidia-auto-select +0+1200"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Notice that all displays are part of a single X screen (as desired), and the layout is specified in the "metamodes" option.  If I use `startx`, everything works correctly.

However, LightDM seems to reset the layout mysteriously at some point before displaying the login screen.

I see the following snippet early on in `Xorg.0.log`, configuring screens correctly:

> [  5601.023] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes: [  5601.023] (II)
>   NVIDIA(0):     [  5601.023] (II) NVIDIA(0):
>   "DP-4:nvidia-auto-select+1920+0,DP-5:nvidia-auto-select+0+0,DP-6:nvidia-auto-select+1920+1200,DP-7:nvidia-auto-select+0+1200" [  5601.023] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3840
>   x 2400

But with LightDM, I get the following later on in the log (with `X -logverbose 6`):

```
[  1022.497] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1022.497] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1022.497] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1022.497] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1022.497] (II) XKB: Reusing cached keymap
[  1023.181] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:2 position:0,0 mode:null rotation:0x01 output:null)
[  1023.194] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1023.194] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1023.194] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-7)
[  1023.194] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-7: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+1200 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
[  1023.644] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:3 position:0,0 mode:null rotation:0x01 output:null)
[  1023.646] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1023.646] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1023.646] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
[  1023.970] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetScreenSize(screen:0 size:7680x1200 sizeMM:2032x318)
[  1023.987] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using 8388608 bytes for software rendering cache
[  1024.050] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:2 position:3840,0 mode:1920x1200 rotation:0x01 output:DP-6)
[  1024.053] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1024.053] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1024.053] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-6)
[  1024.053] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-6: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
[  1024.394] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:3 position:5760,0 mode:1920x1200 rotation:0x01 output:DP-7)
[  1024.397] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1024.397] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1024.397] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-6)
[  1024.397] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-7)
[  1024.397] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-6: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-7: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +5760+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
[  1024.853] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:1 position:0,0 mode:1920x1200 rotation:0x01 output:DP-4)
[  1024.856] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1024.856] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1024.856] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-6)
[  1024.856] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-7)
[  1024.856] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-6: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-7: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +5760+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
[  1024.920] (II) NVIDIA(0): XRRSetCrtcConfig(screen:0 crtc:0 position:1920,0 mode:1920x1200 rotation:0x01 output:DP-5)
[  1024.923] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-5)
[  1024.923] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-4)
[  1024.923] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-6)
[  1024.923] (II) NVIDIA(0): Screen transformation disabled for HP Z24i (DFP-7)
[  1024.923] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-6: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-7: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +5760+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
```

My LightDM config files are all standard except for `90-nvidia.conf` which has probably been installed by proprietary Nvidia drivers:

```
# ls /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
50-greeter-wrapper.conf
50-guest-wrapper.conf
50-ubuntu.conf
50-unity-greeter.conf 
50-xserver-command.conf
90-nvidia.conf
# ls /etc/lightdm/
users.conf
```

Also, I have tried removing `90-nvidia.conf` but that didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `unity-greeter` which is the default LightDM greeter applies that Unity display settings once it gets launched.  I have configured my monitor layout in Unity display settings in addition to `xorg.conf`, but this does not help

Since I am using a different window manager (i3), `unity-settings-daemon` is not running, and this appears to cause the greeter to fall back to the horizontal layout, replacing what `xorg.conf` requested and ignoring the Unity display settings.

Comment: I also found this topic with users suffering from unity-greeter  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/915468  And no fix even for ubuntu-14.04, unfortunately.

Comment: OP is right, the unity-greeter messes everythig up. Installing the lightdm-gtk-greeter fixes the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something wrong with **current** X-org or with current NVidia drivers and software, or it's about 64-bit versions.

I had a bit simiar issue (not reading settings?) with NVidia Quadro NVS140M on 64-bit Debian 7.

It was something wrong with default video settings. I had horrible color hue offset (blue faces, red trees or something like that). I was able to correct them with nvidia-settings application, but colors were crazy after restart, until I started nvidia-settings again. When I started it - it looked like configuration file was read and colors were configured again without any change, just after starting nvidia-settings.

Few years ago I was using same hardware with some older driver, older linux (I think it was SuSE) and it was 32 bit version. Maybe try to uninstall xorg or video driver and try some older version. I guess that solution is not desireable too, but... I don't have any other ideas.

And one more tip for future - next time consider using more "serious" linux distribution, like SuSE Enterprise or maybe Debian 6.

Comment: I think in my case, it has something to do with LightDM.  If I use startx, screens are laid out according to xorg.conf, but if I do "sudo start lightdm" instead, I get the linear layout.  I also see a few extra lines in Xorg.0.log, suggesting that something is changing the layout later.  I just can't find the script that's doing this!

Comment: Why you are using lightdm? Problems with OpenGL or Java rendering under new Gnome?

Comment: It's the default that comes with the distribution.  I'm also using i3 as my window manager.  I have edited the question to make it more lightdm-specific.

Comment: I think you should show how you tried to fix that with `xrandr`. You don't want to put your configuration to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config`? (which is probably overriding your configuration somehow)

Comment: I completely removed my `xrandr` "fix" before generating those logs.  I will update the question with files under `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` just in case there is something there.

Comment: OK, it looks like it has something to do with `unity-greeter`.  Changing the LightDM greeter to another one fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've found [this list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM) of troubleshootings, with a possible solution to your problem. I've the same too, LigthDM swaps the order of the monitors.